# Download data with a S3 link

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I explore a tools produced by the World Ressources Institute (WRI) called the Aqueduct. This is realize as part of my internship, the purpose is to create a water stress indicator which will potentially be based on this tools of the WRI.
So during my research I found a github with all the script they used for the Aqueduct. Their data seems to be stored in S3 part of the Amazon web Services, because they shared this link: s3://wri-projects/Aqueduct30. But I don't know what to do with this link and how I can access to their data.
The github: https://github.com/wri/Aqueduct30Docker

Comment: Get an AWS account and then access https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/wri-projects

Answer (score 0):

One of the links I found using search on their repo: https://wri-projects.s3.amazonaws.com/Aqueduct30/finalData/Y2019M04D15_RH_GA_Aqueduct_Results_Clean_V01/Y2019M07D17_RH_GA_Aqueduct30_Rankings_V01.xlsx

You may assume that `https://wri-projects.s3.amazonaws.com/Aqueduct30/` is a web url of that S3 they are referring to I think.